# function prototype inheritance with new keyword

Tags: javascript, prototype, new-operator

I was making sure that I understood JavaScript's `new` and `prototype` keywords correctly but some simple code I put together is not behaving as I expect.

```
var ClassA = function() {
    return {
        shout: function() {
             alert("I can shout");
        }
    };
};
ClassA.prototype.shoutLouder = function() {
     alert("I CAN SHOUT");
};

var instance = new ClassA();
instance.shout();

// why not available?
instance.shoutLouder();
```

When the instance variable attempts to invoke `shoutLouder` it's failing with *"Uncaught TypeError: instance.shoutLouder is not a function"*.

But, in the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), it says that when using `new` to create an object:

> A new object is created, inheriting from Foo.prototype.

Where am I wrong in my understanding?

[Here is a jsbin](https://jsbin.com/qezihujoga/edit?html,js,output) for the above code-snippit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're losing access to the function's (Class') prototype object because you're returning a new object out of the function:

```
var ClassA = function() {
    return {
        shout: function() {
             alert("I can shout");
        }
    };
};
```

whereas you should be doing:

```
var ClassA = function() {
    this.shout = function() {
        alert("I can shout");
    };
};
```

This will still give you access to the prototype object (and thus the delegation chain will still work) because the new keyword will return 'this' from the Class.

Answer (score 1):

`ClassA` returns a new , different object

```
 return {
        shout: function() {
             alert("I can shout");
        }
    };
```

Try

```
var ClassA = function() {
    this.shout = function() {
             alert("I can shout");            
    };
};
ClassA.prototype.shoutLouder = function() {
     alert("I CAN SHOUT");
};

var instance = new ClassA();

instance.shout();

// why not available?
instance.shoutLouder();
```